# HD Key Derivation for ED25519

Tags: ledger, wallets, cryptography, trezor

I'm currently looking into implementing HD Key derivation for Tezos addresses, and while there's plenty of implementations and standards regarding SECP256k1 addresses, from my understanding it would be preferable to work with tz1 addresses (for threshold schemes, for example).

So far the only concrete thing I've found while looking into this is [Trezor's SLIP-10](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0010.md), but since compatibility with other implementations would be the major concern I'm curious to know whether this is a widely accepted standard for ED25519, and if it is implemented by others (Ledger, for example) as well?

If  not, I'd greatly appreciate if anyone could point me in a better direction!